# What are the plugins to insert code snippets in website?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, code-snippets

It wld be best if the plugins have syntax highlighting function for html,css and javascript

Answer (score 1):

Most websites I know use Alex Gorbatchev's famous [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) javascript library. This is a very popular library and it supports CSS, JavaScript, HTML out of the box (see the available "[brushes](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter:Brushes)").